# pug doesn't iterate array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, express-validator

i'm using `express-validator` and when i log my errors, everything is fine:

```
 errors:
   [ { value: '',
       msg: 'Email Field is empty',
       param: 'email',
       location: 'body' },
     { value: '',
       msg: 'Your email is not valid',
       param: 'email',
       location: 'body' } ] }
```

in my `register.pug` view:

```
   if(errors)
      .alert.alert-danger
          ul.mb-0
             each error in errors
                li=error.msg
```

this is my route:

```
router.post(
  "/register",
  [
    check("email")
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("Email Field is empty"),
    check("email")
      .isEmail()
      .withMessage("Your email is not valid")
  ],
  function(req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    res.render("register", { errors });
  }
);
```

this is output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZfTQ.png)

it doesn't display error messages.
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your console.log I think the `errors` variable is an object containing the key `errors`.

So when you do `each error in errors`, `error` is equal to the `errors` array because the loop is indexing into the object instead of the array.

This would mean that you'd have to change the res.render to either `res.render("register", errors);` or `res.render("register", { errors: errors.errors });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a problem but i normally do it this way:

res.render("register", { "errors": errors });

and then:

li=#{error.msg}

Comment: error fixed by removing = but the problem still exists

Comment: the `res.render` call wouldn't make a difference unless the version of nodejs is old because `{ errors }` is just shorthand for `{ errors: errors }`